# Poor conventional machine learning algorithms results on a multi class Time Series classification problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, time-series, classification

I am using python for a time series classification problem. The problem is as follows: there are some labels(approximately 6 ones) based on mainly 6 features captures on identical time intervals (every 0.5 second, we have 6 features as the time series representation. For example, at the first 0.5 second we have [80, 81 , 67, 100, 105, 99] as the features and so on. Every 0.5 second there is a label assigned to the 6 features list so that for the first 0.5 second the label is 1 and for the next one the label is 2 and ...). The task is to classify each 6 features list and assign the proper label. The data structure is as follows: [feature1 , feature2, feature3, feature4, feature5, feature6, label]
**I cannot use Deep Learning methods just focus on machine machine learning/mathematical methods**.

I tried different ways to manually extract features like mean, average, std, (using sliding window or even with out using sliding window) and ... . Also used different algorithms like SVM, KNN, and Decision Tree but none of the methods have good results (poor accuracy around 72% for train/test part). Tested preprocessing methods like standard scaler but did not improve the accuracy that much. I have provided a sample of the data set at [this link](https://mega.nz/file/QbMX3TgY#i6kIJlFtHflroPCceukMYvUqhrFu33ZNt5hRB7GTb6s).
Any help is encouraged so that I would be thankful if you share the code based on your ideas.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.